# Accessing React Hooks State with Jest Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I am looking for a way to check if my state updated appropriately in my hooks component.  The component is a simple dropdown menu which opens and closes when clicked.

I have tried a few different methods of mounting the component in my test and using jest mock functions. However I haven't been able to find a way to test if state updates.

I have a component `Dropdown` with a function `handleClick`:

```
const Dropdown = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(prev => !prev);
  };
```

I have a button in a `div` which when clicked will toggle the state of my hook:

```
<div>
          <Button
            className="classes.menuButton"
            onClick={handleClick}
            aria-label="menu"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} />
          </Button>
</div
```

My unit test is trying to mount the component, simulate a click, and then evaluate state.

```
it('clicking button toggles open', () => {
    let results;
    function HookWrapper(){
      results = Dropdown();
      return null;
     };
    mount(<HookWrapper />)
    // console.log(results.state)
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    // console.log(wrapper.find('button').debug())
    expect(results.open).toEqual(true)
  })
```

I am getting an error telling me that results.open is undefined. 
Is there any way I can access the hooks state?
I'm also wondering if it would be better to turn this into a snapshot test. Take a snapshot after the button is clicked and compare.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how does your `open` affects render result?

Comment: I conditionally render an element in the return function.

Comment: @skyboyer {open ? <Paper> ... </ Paper> : null}

Answer (score 0):

It's better not working with state in test even when you can. There are several reasons, let's start from that related to maintenance: any single refactoring(to functional component, to redux-connected, wrapping with HOC, restructuring state) may break tests and it's road to hell. You don't want this. Also this would cut half of value tests bring(feel of assurance during refactoring).

So set props, run callback props on nested components and validate render result

```
expect(wrapper.find(Paper)).toHaveLength(0);
wrapper.find(Button).prop("onClick")();
expect(wrapper.find(Paper)).toHaveLength(1);
wrapper.find(Button).prop("onClick")();
expect(wrapper.find(Paper)).toHaveLength(0);
```

Easy-peasy.